# POST array to Spring's controller via AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send object's array to Spring controller via jQuery AJAX.
Here is the javascript code:

```
var data = new Array();
            $.each(products, function (i) {
                var temp = {};
                temp.orpid = products[i].orpid;
                temp.orpah = $('#orpah' + products[i].orpid).is(':checked');
                temp.orpad = $('#orpad' + products[i].orpid).val();
                data.push(temp);
            });
            $.postJSON(url + 'save',
                    data,
                    function(response) {
                        if (response.isAuthenticated && response.isAuthorized) {
                            if (response.hasErrors) {
                                $('#routeForm').setErrors(response.errors);
                                hideWait();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            redirectToLogin();
                    });
```

Here are the params that are sent to the server:

```
[{"orpid":10,"orpah":false,"orpad":""},{"orpid":11,"orpah":false,"orpad":""}]
```

The controller's method has following definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = BaseController.AJAX_HEADER)
public ModelAndView save(@RequestBody HandlingOrderProductActionForm form, HttpServletResponse response) {...}
```

where HandlingOrderProductActionForm is:

```
public class HandlingOrderProductActionForm extends BaseForm {  
public class ActionForm {
    private Boolean orpah;
    private String orpad;
    private Long orpid;

    public ActionForm() { }

    public void setOrpah(Boolean orpah) {
        this.orpah = orpah;
    }

    public Boolean getOrpah() {
        return orpah;
    }

    public void setOrpad(String orpad) {
        this.orpad = orpad;
    }

    public String getOrpad() {
        return orpad;
    }

    public void setOrpid(Long orpid) {
        this.orpid = orpid;
    }

    public Long getOrpid() {
        return orpid;
    }
}

private List<ActionForm> actions;

/**
 * 
 */
public HandlingOrderProductActionForm() {
    super();
}

public void setActions(List<ActionForm> actions) {
    this.actions = actions;
}

public List<ActionForm> getActions() {
    return actions;
} }
```

The problem is, that the server returns an 415 error:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem is solved - just move the ActionForm to separate class!