# Can not deserialize instance of CUSTOM_CLASS out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to send an objects array to Spring controller via jQuery AJAX.
Here is the javascript code:

```
var data = new Array();
        $.each(products, function (i) {
            var temp = {};
            temp.orpid = products[i].orpid;
            temp.orpah = $('#orpah' + products[i].orpid).is(':checked');
            temp.orpad = $('#orpad' + products[i].orpid).val();
            data.push(temp);
        });
        $.postJSON(url + 'save',
                data,
                function(response) {
                    if (response.isAuthenticated && response.isAuthorized) {
                        if (response.hasErrors) {
                            $('#routeForm').setErrors(response.errors);
                            hideWait();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        redirectToLogin();
                });
```

The params that are sended to server:

```
[{"orpid":10,"orpah":false,"orpad":""},{"orpid":11,"orpah":false,"orpad":""}]
```

The problem is that server response with 500 error:

```
Can not deserialize instance of XXX out of START_ARRAY token
```

where xxx is the name of my custom form class.

Could somebody explain me where is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like your server side code is attempting to read an instance of `XXX` from the JSON output rather than an array of `XXX`. Can you post a sample of the code used?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. You can see the whole picture here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671930/post-array-to-springs-controller-via-ajax, except of fact that problem described there already solved. I moved the ActionForm to separate class

Comment: matt b, thanks. You were right. I changed the array into object and it work fine:) Thanks!

Comment: Nice work nKognito. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671930/post-array-to-springs-controller-via-ajax). Only thing you have to do is to create separate object at server side.